# ionic 'DocumentScanner' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have the following code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {DocumentScanner, DocumentScannerOptions, DocumentScannerSourceType} from '@ionic-native/document-scanner';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-tab2',
    templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})
export class Tab2Page {

    constructor(private documentScanner: DocumentScanner) {
    }

    scan() {
        const opts: DocumentScannerOptions = {
            sourceType: DocumentScannerSourceType.CAMERA,
            fileName: 'ticketScan.png',
            quality: 100,
            returnBase64: true
        };
        this.documentScanner.scanDoc(opts)
            .then((res: string) => console.log(res))
            .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
    }
}
```

When i run this i get the following error:

```
11:42 'DocumentScanner' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
```

can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 5):

You need to import DocumentScanner in your app.module.ts file

```
import { DocumentScanner } from '@ionic-native/document-scanner/ngx';
```

and also add it to the provider array

```
providers: [
.....
   DocumentScanner ,
.....
]
```

Also in your page.ts file, add /ngx/; after the document scanner import path like

```
import { DocumentScanner } from '@ionic-native/document-scanner/ngx/';
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-ts2749-device-refers-to-a-value-but-is-being-used-as-a-type-here-did-you-mean-typeof-device/197147), if **any** file in your project has a missing `/ngx` import, it may cause issues even in files where `/ngx` is present.

So you should check every file for missing `/ngx` imports.